# Use Nimbus look and feel on Netbeans IDE 7.1.2

Tags: netbeans, addition, look-and-feel, nimbus

In Netbeans IDE 7.1.2 by default i have three look and feel:

- Metal;
- CDE/Motif;
- GTK+.

Is it possible to add the Nimbus or other look and feel?
Thanks.
(i downloaded the Netbeans 7.3 but there are still the three look and feel cited above)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the L&F for netbeans or your program?

To set Nimbus for NetBeans you can start it with the commandline argument `--laf`:

```
   ./netbeans --laf com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
```

*(or netbeans exe on windows)*

To make this permanent add the line mentioned above to  `netbeans.conf`, line `netbeans_default_options=` (path of the file: `<netbeans path>/etc/`).

Btw. Nimbus requires at least *Java 6 update 10*.